# Перенаправление потока вывода и потока ошибок в конец файла

Tags: linux, bash, командная-строка

Можно перенаправить поток вывода и(или) ошибок в файл с его перезаписью:
`1>file` выведет данные с потока вывода в файл с его созданием или перезаписью
`2>file` выведет данные с потока ошибок в файл с его созданием или перезаписью
`1&>file` (и несколько других вариантов) выведут данные и с потока вывода и с потока ошибок в файл с его созданием и перезаписью.

Можно выводить поток вывода или поток ошибок в файл, записывая в его конец:

```
1>>file 2>>file
```

Но если попробовать сделать что-то вроде `1&>>file`, то выскочит синтаксическая ошибка.

Как можно записывать в конец файла и с потока вывода и с потока ошибок?

Comment: Спасибо. Как ни странно, пробовал похожий вариант:
2&>1 >>file, и возращалось сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Ничего странного, если допускаете ошибку, то выводится сообщение об ошибке. И поправте вопрос - какая ОС,  какой shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например в Bash так:

```
$ { echo "stdout text"; echo "stderr text">&2; } >> file 2>&1
$ cat file
stdout text
stderr text
```

Bash выполняет перенаправление слева направо:

1. `>>file`: открывает file в режиме до записи и перенаправляет туда стандартный вывод (`stdout`)
2. `2>&1`: перенаправляет вывод ошибок (`stderr`) туда, куда в настоящий момент выводится стандартный вывод, т.е. в открытый ранее файл `file`.

`cmd 2>&1 >> file` перенаправит только стандартный вывод в file, т.к вывод ошибок будет перенаправлен на стандартный вывод до того, как последний будет перенаправлен в файл:

```
$ { echo "stdout text"; echo "stderr text">&2; } 2>&1 >> file
stderr text
$ cat file
stdout text
```