# Что делает ">> файл"?

Tags: linux, grep, root, ps

Что делает команда

```
$ ps -aux | grep root | wc -l >> root
```

Смогла разобраться ровно до стрелочек. ***`ps -aux | grep root | wc -l`*** подсчитает количество процессов пользователя root, верно? А что делает ***`>> root`***?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Перенаправление потока вывода и потока ошибок в конец файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764865/178576)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верно, `ps -aux` выводит список процессов. `grep root` берёт из вывода только строки, в которых есть подстрока `root`. `wc -l` считает количество символов перевода строки (т.е. количество строк), ну а `>> root` - это перенаправление вывода программы в файл с именем `root`, но, в отличие от `>`, `>>` дописывает данные в конец файла, а не удаляет содержимое файла перед записью. В итоге получается, что вся команда дописывает в конец файла `root` количество строк из вывода `ps -aux`, в которых есть подстрока `root`. Можете проверить сами, просто после выполнения команды выполните `cat root`.

Comment: `количество процессов пользователя root` — сначала ж написано правильно: `строки, в которых есть слово root`. буквосочетание `root` может встретиться в выводе *ps* в разных местах.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вы правы. Исправил.

Comment: Ещё точнее «последовательность из четырёх букв root», чтобы было слово надо использовать `grep -w`. @aleksandrbarakin, незачёт.